# Where is the Location of MSDN Documentation on Local Machine

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msdn

I installed VS 2012 and chose ALL the options to install the documentation which I assume was for the MSDN.  However, I have no idea where it installed to.  I am wondering if anyone knows where the default location would be or how to find it.

I am assuming what was installed was similar to the Java API that is downloaded and is stored in a folder with some sort of navigational method to it.

Comment: How do I actually utilize it after locating the folder. With Java there was an Index.htm file to navigate through all the namespaces and such

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In VS 2012, the location of the local help documentation is displayed in the right-hand corner of the "Manage Content" tab.  The default local store path is:  C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\HelpLibrary2\Catalogs\VisualStudio11\

Help Viewer 2.0 (ships with VS 2012) enables you to move your local store to a location of your choice.  Click on the "Move..." button in the "Manage Content" tab to do this.

Under the covers, the local store path is stored in the following registry key:

**Key location**: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Help\v2.0\Catalogs\VisualStudio11

**Key name**: LocationPath

Comment: How do I actually utilize it after locating the folder.  With Java there was an Index.htm file to navigate through all the namespaces and such.

Comment: If you want to better understand the structure of the local store, read this tutorial on how to [create a basic help file](http://thirdblogfromthesun.com/2011/05/create-a-basic-help-file-for-the-microsoft-help-viewer/) for the Microsoft Help Viewer.  If you want to programmatically access the content, check out the [HV 2.0 Runtime API](http://helpviewer2.codeplex.com/) samples on CodePlex.